# How to create a library that uses DI inside and use in a project that doesn't use DI?

Tags: c#, configuration, service-locator, dependency-inversion

Hy guys,

I need to create a library in a project, which uses DI internally, like that:

**Library**

```
namespace Library
{
    public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {
        private readonly IOtherService _otherService;

        public SomeService(IOtherService otherService,
                             IConfiguration configuration) { /* constructor stuff */ }

       //... class stuff

    }
}
```

But it will be used, as a nuget package, in another project that doesn't use DI directly.

What is the best way to resolve the dependencies of this library, and instantiate de service on the client project?

I'm considering creating an entrypoint with ServiceLocator pattern, and provide it to the client, is this the only way (or the best way) for this job?

Is there another way to build a library like this?

EDIT: I'm using a DI framework internally to wire up classes inside the library. And client project have a startup registering the dependencies, but classes are not prepared to receive the instances in the constructor.

Comment: There's a difference between using dependency injection, and using a dependency injection *framework*. Getting `IOtherService` and `IConfiguration` injected in a library class is no problem and puts no burden on your consumers, other than that they have to deal with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` (assuming that's where `IConfiguration` comes from). They are free to use Microsoft's framework, or something else, or none at all and call the constructor directly themselves.

Comment: You can try ILMerge or SmartAssembly or any other tool to merge two dlls into one.

Comment: @KrivitskiyGrigoriy that's not what the question is about

Comment: You can use the Configuration classes withouth the DI framework itself. The interfaces come in a *separate* package, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions`. Instead of breaking the library and introducing an *anti* pattern like ServiceLocator, use the Abstractions in the client and pass them to the library. You'll soon find it's actually *easier* to use Configuration like this

Comment: Besides, Configuration is *Configuration*. Not dependency injection. Those abstractions are a well-known, .NET Core/Standard wide *configuration* abstraction. By using them, the library doesn't need *hard-coded* access to some settings file. The *client* provides the configuration values

Comment: If you use a DI framework internally to wire up classes, that detail should ideally not be exposed to consumers as it not only limits their options, but also encourages you to hide your dependencies by passing around overly generic framework classes instead of the dependencies you actually need, which actually defeats the purpose of DI. Ideally don't do it at all, and if you must do it take care not to expose any of those classes as parameters or fields. Even with that you still run the risk of conflicts between versions if the clients use your DI framework as well.

Comment: @JeroenMostert a reminder that the question's *code* doesn't mention DI at all. Only the configuration interfaces. Nothing forces the OP to use an IServiceCollection to pass an `IConfiguration` around. It could even be a singleton for all the client library cares. The OP confuges the configuration interfaces with DI

Comment: `it will be used, as a nuget package, in another project` even more reason to use the de-facto standard interfaces

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, I use a DI framework internally to wire up classes. In this case, what would be the best way to get an instance of my service on the client project? How would my client project solve ISomeService dependencies, since IOtherService also belongs to the library?

Comment: There are two basic scenarios: 1) your client has no reason to pass in an `ISomeService` dependency on their own, because you are the one deciding what the dependency is. In this case, write a wrapper class/facade that takes care of hooking up the dependency so clients don't need to know. 2) Clients do have a need for customizing the dependency, in which case they will pass it in *any way they please*. How they find `IOtherService` is of no concern to you -- you can document this class, and you can offer a sensible default (again, facade) but you should not foist a global locator on them.

Comment: Basically, however you design your library should pass the "what if *every* library did this?" test, and the "what if *every* library used its own, incompatible dependency framework?" test, even before you consider how the scenario with a client application using only your library would get along.